# Wordpress Redirect post to outside website based on useragent

Tags: redirect

I have wordpress site and need advise regarding redirect htaccess based on useragent:

Sample:

my old url: myolddomain/old-post/
redirect to: mynewdomain/new-post/

based on useragent

thanks

Answer (score 0):

using Javascript to get the User Agent. Then based on the User Agent do a redirect.

something like this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent; 

if (ua === 'whatever userAgent you are testing for')
{
   window.location = 'https://newurl.com'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple .htaccess redirects based on user-agents something like this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ opera.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ msie.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ chrome.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ safari.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ firefox.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^abc.html$ default.html [L]
```

In WordPress, there is also some inbuilt action hooks such as "[template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)" You can use this action hook too.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'device_redirect' );

function device_redirect(){
  if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iphone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iphone') ) {
            wp_redirect( "http://www.example.com/iphone", 301 );
    } else if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'android') ) {
           wp_redirect( "http://www.example.com/andriod", 301 );
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that User Agent values can be spoofed, so this is not foolproof.